# Почему jQuery приоритетнее CSS? (и как это исправить)

Tags: jquery, css, background

Вопрос в том, что приоритет операций ***jQuery.css()*** выше чем сам ***CSS***.
Пример:
Имею *CSS* класс **.active**, который делает кнопку темнее при событии *click*.
If { в соседнем блоке :checked хотя бы один `input[type=checkbox]`, то задаем `$(this).next().css('background-color', '#339933'); }` Else { если все ckeckbox'ы пустые, то добавляем наш класс **.active** }.
Да, может быть пример не наилучшый, но все же как-то так.

*Пы.Сы:* решил проблему тем, что добавил класс **.mark** . Вместо `$(this).next().css('background-color', '#339933'); }` . Но вопрос всеравно остался: "Как изменять приоритеты" кроме !important конечно же.

Comment: Потому что приоритет встроенных стилей элемента всегда выше приоритета стилей из css-файлов, это ж самые основы css и jQuery  тут ни при чём

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Приоритеты стилей](https://idg.net.ua/blog/uchebnik-css/azy-css/kaskadnost)

Советую вам ознакомится с самими приоритетами в CSS.

При использовании `jQuery.css()` - он добавляет inline-стили непосредственно в сам атрибут style у тега, а на приоритет jquery никак не влияет.

Используйте `jQuery.addClass()` и руководите своими приоритетами только через CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Иcпользуйте **important!**

Если возникает противоречие, когда стиль автора страницы и пользователя для одного и того же элемента не совпадает, то `!important` позволяет повысить приоритет стиля.

При использовании пользовательской таблицы стилей или одновременном применении разного стиля автора и пользователя к одному и тому же селектору, браузер руководствуется следующим алгоритмом.

*!important* добавлен в авторский стиль — будет применяться стиль автора.

*!important* добавлен в пользовательский стиль — будет применяться стиль пользователя.

*!important* нет как в авторском стиле, так и стиле пользователя — будет применяться стиль автора.

*!important* содержится в авторском стиле и стиле пользователя — будет применяться стиль пользователя.

Comment: Автор правильно сделал, используя класс. Встроенные стили элементов — и так обычно плохая вещь, а !important нужен крайне редко при прямых руках (мне за десять лет раза три всего понадобился)

Comment: @andreymal я часто использую !important когда включаю bootstrap незнаю как вы без него.

Comment: Ну, при прямых руках и bootstrap не нужен, мне за десять лет он ноль раз понадобился :D

Comment: @andreymal ну вы мастер за свои десят лет. а я новичек  по сравнению с вами ;)